# pci_alloc_consistent uncached memory

Tags: linux-kernel, dma, pci, pci-e

Is it fair to say that `pci_alloc_consistent` allocates a contiguous non-cached, non-paged kernel memory chunk. The reason I'm asking is that I saw this comment in some kernel/driver code (not in vanilla kernel sources), and I think I understand that the memory is presented as contiguous, however not sure that it's allocated non-cached, because the idea of cache coherency is to maintain data in the cache and DMA memory consistent.

Also, not sure why they call it non-paged.

E.g. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API.txt in section `Part Ia` says:

*Consistent memory is memory for which a write by either the device or
the processor can immediately be read by the processor or device
without having to worry about caching effects.*

So one can't infer that the memory is *non-cached*, so I tend to think that comments I saw are somewhat misleading.

I would appreciate to get useful comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On x86, the caches are DMA-coherent (which requires that the cache controller snoops all DMA traffic), so consistent memory is just normal (cached) memory.

On most other architectures, caches are not DMA-coherent, so `pci_alloc_consistent()` must allocate non-cached memory.

"Non-paged" means that the memory cannot be swapped to disk. However, this is something that a Windows driver writer would care about; none of the normal Linux kernel allocation function returns swappable memory.